# Validating drop down list where user should not be able to select same role twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The dropdown list contains different roles that need to be assigned to the user. Each user can have multiple role. But user should not be able to select same role twice. How do I validate this? Need help

Dropdown code

```
<%= f.select(:role_id, Role.all.map{|e| [e.name, e.id]},{ include_blank: "Please select"}, multiple: true ) %>
```

Using has_many through association

user_role.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :role
```

Comment: Its better to use this pluging `https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails`

Answer (score 1):

Add a [uniqueness constraint](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) to the `UserRole` model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :role 

validates_uniqueness_of :role_id, :scope => :user_id
```